# How to create any application window that should not pass to projector screen on mac?

Tags: macos, java, hdmi, swing

I want to know there is any way to write a application on mac, and that application window should only visible on screen even that system connected to projector screen.

For Example:

If i write some java swing application and creating a JFrame window, but i want that window only shown on my system screen but not to projector screen even my system is connected to projector.

Alternate way of question is: Can i control my application window should shown to only particular port(Either system screen, HDMI port or any other particular port)

If its possible means, how to control that and this responsibility lies with my application or operating system.

Still if you feel question is confused kindly comment over here will try to explain more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't consider myself an exact expert in Java (An *intermediate* programmer really), but I don't believe that is possible unfortunately. The way the operating system handles window rendering this can't really be done securely, it's not as if the HDMI, or VGA receiver is rendering the image, also think of all the potential security risks this could pose with invisible windows (rendering to a non-used port) running code without your knowledge.

*Summary:* Probably not.